# Issue with Reading two Int values from a file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, readfile, inputmismatchexception

I have file with the below data

```
A,8,43
B,7,42,
C,9,34
```

I am using the below code to read the data

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("D:\\test.txt"));
input.useDelimiter(",|\n");  
while(input.hasNext()) {
   String name = input.next();
   int age = input.nextInt();
   int height = input.nextInt();
```

When I am executing the program I am getting InputMisMatch exception, 
Please suggest what is mistake.

Comment: Use more than one Scanner -- the first using a while loop to read **lines** from the File using `hasNextLine` and `nextLine`, the second within the while loop, using the line String obtained to extract tokens from the line. Match each `hasNextXxx` with a `nextXxx`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At end of second line you have `,` and line separator (I am assuming `\n`) This means you have empty element between these two delimiters.

So in third iteration

```
String name = input.next();  
int age = input.nextInt();
int height = input.nextInt();
```

`input.next();` is consuming `""`, which means `input.nextInt()` will try to consume `C`.

To solve this problem you can set delimiter to be combination of **one or more** commas and line separators like

```
input.useDelimiter("(,|\n)+");
```

To improve your code even farther instead of `\n` you can use `\\R` added in Java 8 (or `\r|\n` in earlier versions) to handle all line separators, because currently you don't consider `\r` as delimiter so it can be treated as valid token.

So better solution would be using

```
input.useDelimiter("(,|\\R)+"); //for readability
```

or even

```
input.useDelimiter("[,\r\n]+");
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies at the use of the `useDelimiter` method. This method accepts a *regular expression* as a parameter. You can't just say `,|\n` to mean "comma or new line". There are [rules](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

What you should pass in is `"[,\\n]+"`. This means "one or more characters in the following set: [comma, new line character]".

With the regex that you are passing currently, `,|\n`, it means that the delimiter should be either `,` or `\n`, but not both. So when it encounters the second line:

```
B,7,42,
```

this is what happens:

- `next` reads "B"
- `nextInt` reads "7"
- `nextInt` reads "42"
- `next` reads an empty string that is between the "," and the new line.
- `nextInt` now tries to read the next token "C", which it can't.
- EXCEPTION!

Answer (score 1):

I would do things differently -- use one Scanner to parse each line of the File and use a 2nd Scanner nested within the while loop to extract tokens or data from the lines obtained from the first Scanner.  For example:

```
String filePath = "D:\\test.txt";
File file = new File(filePath);

// use try-with-resources
try (Scanner input = new Scanner(file)) {
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = input.nextLine();
        Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line);
        lineScanner.useDelimiter("\\s*,\\s*"); // get comma and any surrounding whitespace if present
        String name = "";
        int age = 0;
        int height = 0;
        if (lineScanner.hasNext()) {
            name = lineScanner.next();
        } // else ... throw exception?
        if (lineScanner.hasNextInt()) {
            age = lineScanner.nextInt();
        } // else ... throw exception?
        if (lineScanner.hasNextInt()) {
            height = lineScanner.nextInt();
        } // else ... throw exception?

        // use name, age, height here
        System.out.printf("%s %s %s%n", name, age, height);

        lineScanner.close(); // don't waste resources -- return them
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```